# clustering text with python

Tags: python, similarity, hierarchical-clustering

I decide to play a little with similarities and clustering text.

I have already create the tf-idf and symmatrix matrix of similarities. Now I want to implement something for clustering into groups.

I made a research and I have found hcluster and k-means libraries.

Which of those is better in base of accuracy? Do you know any better way even if there isn't a ready library. I could write the code if I knew the algorithm.

Also, this way is O(n^2). If I would like to sacrifize a little of accuracy to win on calculating time, do you have something to suggest?

Comment: Might be too broad for stackoverflow.  You're basically asking for papers here.

Comment: Is there any other stack exchange where my question fit better?

Comment: [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) might be an appropriate place.  You could probably answer this question, however, with some online research using Google Scholar; especially if you already feel comfortable implementing algorithms based on description and pseudo-code.  My hunch is that accuracy will depend on your classification domain.